# CRUD operations with connected POCOs instead of disconnected POCOs in EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, crud, dbcontext

I have an classic 3 layer project, that has these layers:

- UI (WinForm Project)
- BLL
- DAL(using EF codefirst)

My entities are disconnected `POCO`s and I used them to pass data between layers and used them to bind to the UI controls.

I load a graph of some related entities to UI(e.g. `Order` with it's `OrderLine`s and `Product` of each `OrderLine`), user may add some new entities, edit some others and delete some others entities in this graph, and then send this graph to DAL to persist this changes to DB.

I want to All these CRUD operations apply in one `transaction`. so, for this requirement,  and because my `POCO`s are disconnected, I used following `State` `enum` for my `BaseEntity` class to keep its state in client side(all other entities inherited from `BaseEntity`):

```
public enum States
    {
        Unchanged,
        Added,
        Modified,
        Deleted
    }
```

In DAL, when I want to persist this changed graph of objects, because this entity graph is disconnected from DbContext, I should attach root of my graph to the created DbContext and because after attaching the root to `DbContext` state of all entries in the `DbContext` will be `Added`, I should sync `State` of each `Entry` in DbContext with `State` of entities in my graph, so I used these methods to do this:

```
public static EntityState ConvertState(BaseEntity.States state)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case BaseEntity.States.Added:
            return EntityState.Added;
        case BaseEntity.States.Modified:
            return EntityState.Modified;
        case BaseEntity.States.Deleted:
            return EntityState.Deleted;
        default:
            return EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
}

public void ApplyChanges<TEntity>(TEntity root) where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
   _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(root);
    foreach (var entry in _dbContext.ChangeTracker
    .Entries<BaseEntity>())
    {
        BaseEntity stateInfo = entry.Entity;
        entry.State = ConvertState(stateInfo.State);
    }
}
```

As you see, I am doing a lot of stuff outside of EF and do not use EF features, because my POCOs are disconnected.

Is there any way to apply these bulk CRUD scenario, without disconnecting my `POCO`s from `DbContext`?

Comment: Why not use classic entities, view models and a mapper like automapper to do the translation?  Then you get all the functionality of an ORM like EF.  You are reinventing the wheel here a bit and I am not clear why.

Comment: @Maess is right, if you use view models you will be able to apply all your changes to the context and save all at once. Then all the states will be handles by the context automatically. Your other option is to create and use a context in your UI, but that creates really strong code smell.

Comment: @Maess :Could I apply this scenario with this method?

Comment: You could use it to determine the context state for the entity, yes. But if you use the Onion architecture, calling the appropriate repository method will abstract that away.

Comment: @Maess : Is there any good sample for this method?

Comment: http://onionarch.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Maess : Is this method work for WinForms also?

Comment: Yes.  Unit of Work and Repository patterns are not specific to MVC

Comment: @DanielGabriel : But I think, if I use view Models, when I fetch my data from DB using an instance of DbContext, and map them to views, when I want to persistence the changes, that instance of DbContext isn't exists, and this cause the same problem(copy changes from poco's state to DbContext)

Comment: @Maess : If I want to use the method that you said, I have to use an IoC for managing my DbContext lifetime. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For disconnected POCO entities I have followed this pattern when persisting.

- Get a connected entity graph from the db.
- Map the disconnected graph to the connected one.
- Persist the connected graph.

Currently you are attempting to track changes all the way up through the UI, when these changes may or may not be relevant by the time you are ready to persist, which is cumbersome at best.  I have found that getting the most recent entity from the db just prior to persisting works out much better.

This also gives you the ability to check for concurrency issues when performing the mapping.

Comment: But in your method(in first step) I must Get connected entity graph from db and this transaction smells some type of duplication.

Comment: Finally, I used this method, with graphdiff :)