# Lifetime of DbContext in EF code first in WinForm Projects

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, poco, dbcontext

Recently I asked a question([CRUD operations with connected POCOs instead of disconnected POCOs in EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20478439/1594487)), and based on that and this comment([CRUD operations with connected POCOs instead of disconnected POCOs in EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478439/crud-operations-with-connected-pocos-instead-of-disconnected-pocos-in-ef-code-fi#comment30603913_20478439)), now I want to use connected `POCOs` in my project, so I have another question.

But I think, if I use view models, when I fetch my data from DB using an instance of `DbContext`, and map them to views, when I want to persistence user changes, the prior instance of `DbContext`(that fetched data)isn't exists now(because e.g. when I call `GetOrders()` from my DAL the `DbContext` created and then disposed) and so I should manage my `POCOs` state on client side and copy back them to newly created DbContext(in `SaveOrder()` of my DAL).

Am I correct?

Comment: you are correct. You are in a "MVC paradigm": the view being the winform and the controller, functionally equivalent to a web server, is called from a separate assembly through a DTO. (as often as you can). The controller is the link between the DAL and the domain (that is business logic), the domain being itself another assembly. The separation of assembly is not a necessity but it can help to keep things in good place. (here good may be subjective)

Comment: @tschmit007 So how can i fixed this problem?(loosing connected entities state)

Comment: usually I give a connectionString as property to my forms. Form the connection string you can do anything, including instanciate a context. for the state, the same as you do in a web environment.

Comment: @tschmit007: But I think this is not good idea, because violate SOC.(mixing DAL works with UI)

Comment: right, that's is why UI instanciate a repository (that is an concrete implementation of an interface) that exposes some access methods. The repository builds the context (DAL) from the connection string obtained by the form or any injection method. So the form (UI) uses an interface disregarding the interface implementation.

Comment: @tschmit007 But even I use this way, when I create another instance of DbContext, this one isn't the same as first one that created when I called GetOrder() method.

Comment: Yes, you will use 2 different instance of DbContext. This is not the only way. This is one way. By doing this you will limit some leak as, for example, crash of the form leaving an open connection to the db. You will also enhance, nearly without realize,  concurrency access managment... and so on. And you will get web ready assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You can define DbContext variable as static field on DAL class to fix this problem.

```
        private static YourAppContainer _dbContainer;
        public static YourAppContainer DbContext
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return _dbContainer ?? (_dbContainer = new YourAppContainer());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: But if I set my DbContext static, want about using of my DAL in separate tier? I means that if my DAL shared between multiple users(in server side) then I think your solution does not work correctly.

Comment: You should create a facade class in your DAL layer to access to DAL methods and other members. Also multiple user & multithreading was supported in entity framework and don't worry about it.